# Move windows onto main display when connecting main display

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors, windows-11

I have 2 monitors: a horizontal 2560x1440 ("Main") monitor and a vertical 1920x1080 monitor ("Secondary"). This is the primary configuration I use these in.

[image: Main monitor, horizontal]
[image: Secondary monitor, vertical]

For work, I use a DisplayPort switch that changes the connection to the Main monitor from my desktop to my laptop. I then use the Secondary monitor horizontally for my desktop via Chrome Remote desktop.

[image: Using only the Secondary]

However, when I switch the Main display from my laptop to my desktop, all windows are kept on the Secondary display, in vertical mode, leading to a mess that I have to drag over to the Main monitor. (Sometimes windows move over correctly, but usually maximized windows don't move.)

**Before:**
[image: Before switching]

**After:**
[image: After switching]

Is there a way to have the windows on the Secondary monitor be moved over to the Main display when the Main display is plugged in/switched to?

Comment: There are [many utilities](https://www.makeuseof.com/software-manage-dual-monitors/) that help out doing what you are trying to do.  I am not sure about Windows 11 compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design in Windows.

DisplayPort acts as a PNP device, so turning off a monitor disconnects it from the computer as if it was removed and windows are moved out because Windows forgets this device, until it is turned on again and is "discovered".

One solution is to just let the screen go into sleep instead of turning it off.
There are ways of programmatically forcing that, for example by using the
`monoff` command in the free [Wizmo](https://www.grc.com/wizmo/wizmo.htm) utility to turn off all monitors.

A solution for NVIDIA cards is detailed in
[Managing a Display EDID on windows](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3569/%7E/managing-a-display-edid-on-windows)
by setting the monitor to use
[EDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data) information from a file instead of
from the monitor, so auto-detect is in effect dis-activated.

Another method uses the old and free utility for setting up the EDID
is the
[Custom Resolution Utility (CRU)](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU),
which might still work today.